# Jqgrid Date sorting issue with day name and date column

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

In my Jqgrid table I have a column which has dayName, Date as value,
like, **Wed, 01-03-217**,

But when I add complete data having days as Tue or Thu, jqgrid shows `undefined, NaN-NaN-NaN` as column values for both days,

I am using Jqgrid versoin 4.6.0

I have also prepare demo at fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/alpeshjikadra/jss5b43j/1/

Let me know if anyone knows how to solve this

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage of localized format as the input data (texts like "Thu") in the date is bad practice in general. It's better to change the format of data to use ISO 8601 date format. I mean to post the date "Thu, 09-03-2017" like "2017-03-09".

If you really can't change the format of input data, I could suggest you the following workaround: you can include the line

```
$.jgrid.formatter.date.parseRe = /[,\s\-]/;
```

in your code. The `parseRe` be used internally for parsing the dates. The input format which you use, for example, "Thu, 09-03-2017" contains `-`, spaces and `,` as separators between the parts of the date. The regex `/[,\s\-]/` corresponds the format.

Resulting demo will be http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/jss5b43j/6/

Answer (score 0):

I think there's something with the formatting. 
Try removing the ',' from your invdate property strings in `mydata` eg.: `{id:"1", invdate:"Wed 01-03-2017"}`

It works for some reason.